# Telegram-бот перестал работать, рассылая спам с ошибкой

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Код на python, который запускает Telegram-бота с помощью pyTelegramBotAPI, спокойно работал в течение 20 часов, затем перестал работать без причины и начал рассылать сообщение об ошибке:

```
Telebot: Unhandled exception (full traceback for debug level): ChatBoost.__init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'boost_id', 'add_date', and 'expiration_date
```

Это когда я запускаю с хоста в германии, но когда я запускаю тот же код на своём пк, то спамит ошибкой:

```
ERROR - TeleBot: "Unhandled exception (full traceback for debug level): 'source'"
```

Я пробовал менять токен того же бота, не сработало

Comment: `full traceback for debug level` запустите его, пожалуйста, в режиме отладки. Сообщение о том, что произошла ошибка и все, пользы почти не дает